# My image is very tiny on a mobile - with 320 +

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that used to display ok, [screenshot of small image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQGch.jpg), but now it is making itself very tiny when before it used to fill the mobile screen. This is the CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%; height: auto; text-align: center; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px #888;
}
a img {
    list-style-type: none; text-align: center;
}
```

The image itself has a width of 320px so you would think it would fit but it is very tiny, here i a screenshot. the map image is the one that is tiny, the other is OK

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: Post your HTML too.

Answer (score 1):

Set the HTML viewport to fix this issue. This instructs mobile devices to use certain scaling methods, making the images appear in the correct size.

```
<head>
    <!-- Other head elements here -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```